# PHP how to run php inside php without redirect?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, post

I have two php files. abc.php and def.php
I want to execute only abc.php in browser and only abc.php should be visible in the browser URL bar.
When submit button is clicked on my html page then abc.php should execute and pass the data of form to def.php in background using POST and def.php should not be visible in URL. is that possible?

Comment: Learn AJAX man! This is what you are looking for!

Comment: jQuery .post() is shorthand for .ajax() https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: Will learn but can you answer the question with code for the time being to achieve that

Comment: `abc.php` can use `cURL` to post to `def.php`.

Comment: What research have you performed and how as it helpful?  How was it not helpful?  What criteria did you use?  Have you attempted any code yet?  If you have, then please include a sample of it and the full text of any error messages it is generating.  For more information on how to post a Question, please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 1):

abc.php

```
<script>
$.post( "def.php",{parameter: 'value'}, function( data ) {
   if (data == 'success'){
       alert( 'succeeded' );
   }else{
       alert( 'failed' );
   }
}); 
</script>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

def.php

```
<?php
     // Do your functions here
     function this(){
         // do stuff
      }  or die('fail');
?>
success
```

Comment: How can i return from def.php to abc.php that def.php is successfully executed or not? of course def.php does not include any echo statement

Comment: The alert will show the output of the file `def.php`  --  You can also watch your console to see if a 500 error occurs (F12)

Comment: and www.mywebsite.com/def,php will not be visible in browser url right?

Comment: Correct .. I edited with a slight amount of error handling so you can see how it works ..  If it fails at any point .. `die('fail')` the php script ...  If it reaches the "success" at the bottom, the JS will know it succeeded.\

Comment: Zak is there any way i can achieve this directly using AJAX without including <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: You need the jQuery library in order for that to work..  You can, however go to the URL directly, and save the .js.min locally and use it that way

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I understoond your issue. You have a form in `abc.php`.

When user submits the form PHP should send data to `def.php` and back to `abc.php` without use notices that?

If that's the case, you can do it using AJAX.

In your `abc.php` put an Id into your form and do the code below with jQuery:

`<form method="post" action="" id="ajax_form"> ...`

```
jQuery('#ajax_form').submit(function(){
    var formData= jQuery(this).serialize();
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "def.php",
        data: formData,
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```